Action of Maximal Torus on image of Bruhat Cell
Let $G$ be a connected reductive algebraic group over an algebraically closed field. Let $B$ be a Borel subgroup of $G$ containing a maximal torus $T$. For an element $w$ in the Weyl group $W$ of $G$, let $X(w)$ denote  the image of the double coset $BwB$ under the natural quotient map from $G$ to $G/B$. Then show that there is a unique fixed point in $X(w)$ under the action of $T$.
I think $wB$ should be the unique fixed point. But still I am not able to prove that it is unique and not sure what action is natural. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
